# Can I have a composite shape as a resource in WinRT XAML?

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps, drawingbrush

I'm developing a Windows 8 Metro-style application and I want to use vector images. As there seems to be no direct support for svg images, I am trying to use a xaml fragment consisting of multiple shapes (a path and some lines) as an image. I would like to have a resource dictionary entry with the composite shape and be able to include it in different pages. Ideally, I would also like to be able to resolve a specific composite shape from a data bound property.

From what I've read, the WPF approach was to have a `VisualBrush` or `DrawingBrush` consisting of the shapes, but there are no such classes in Windows 8 (and it seems like it's not even possible to derive from `Brush`).

How am I supposed to do this using WinRT UI?

Comment: Suggestion: forget about XAML, and try implementing what you want in Javascript using an HTML5 Canvas:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2012/03/22/unleash-the-power-of-html-5-canvas-for-gaming-part-1.aspx.  Also check out this link (one of many similar links - and nothing new): http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/54a99549-c634-4d45-87d6-15fd3bab483b/

Comment: PS: You're not supposed to say "Metro" anymore ;) http://www.tomshardware.com/news/Metro-UI-Windows-8-Windows-Phone-Xbox,16784.html

Comment: @paulsm4 I know that this is feasible in HTML but I like C# and XAML (at least when it works) and that's the tech I want to be using. And yeah, I know about the "Metro" term being phased out but the "Windows 8" or "Modern" alternative terms make desktop applications sound too much legacy for my taste :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use a DrawingBrush as the value of a background property in WinRT XAML. It's too bad, huh? Seems like a very powerful features to setup the fill of an object with vector layouts. In fact DrawingBrush is not even part of Windows 8 yet. It is what it is. For now, images are a fine solution. But we feel your pain.

I might as well toss in that VisualBrush is not part of WinRT-XAML either.

Comment: Thanks Jerry! Nice to hear from you, I'm a follower of your blog. Let's hope that this feature makes it in a future update.

Comment: Yes, it's on my wishlist with RadialBrush.

Answer (score 0):

Each XAML fragment is really a UI element.  I think the simplest approach would be to put the XAML into it's own user control and then add the user control to each page you wanted to display the "drawing" on.  If you want the user control to display different shapes, you can expose a property on the control, data bind to that property, and inside the setter of the property read the value and toggle the visibility of the various XAML shapes to show or hide whatever parts of the composite image you want.  It is a bit brute force, but will do what you want.

Comment: Yeah that would work but it doesn't scale very well because then all control instances have the shapes for all possible graphics the application can display. Hopefully there's a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Windows8 way to have vector graphics in it is just to use ViewBox+Canvas and Path elements. It works well in my opinion, though I do miss VisualBrush.