# How to design custom word/speech balloons?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Currently I am working on a project to generate comic pages. One problem I encountered is that I cannot find a good way to generate the word/speech balloons (see one example in the following). How to design such word/speech balloons (e.g. ellipse shape) in C#-XAML? Particularly, I want to design it on the UI so that I can control where the arrow points from and where it points to (maybe by simply dragging on UI).

[image]

I know how to generate one static/fixed version, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23668788/2589776), by manually setting the shape path. For example, we can use the following code to generate something like the following image. But it will become tedious when generating multiple of these with different positions that arrows point from/to by manually setting their paths.

[image]

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="center">
   <Path
      Width="100"
      Data="M 100,119 C 102,109 107,101 120,100 L 220,100 
            C 231,101 241,110 240,120 L 241,159 C 241,170 230,180 220,180 
            L 120,180 C 111,180 100,171 100,160 L 100.5,139.5 L 70,120 Z"
      Fill="#4F81BD"
      Stretch="uniform"
      Stroke="#385D8A"
      StrokeThickness="3"/>
   <TextBlock
      MaxWidth="280"
      Margin="30,15,10,10"
      Text="bla bla bla..."
      TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround solution, as shown in the red part in the following figure, by combining drawing a ellipse and a triangle. Further through filling them with the same background, it should have visually the same effect as the word balloons as in the question.

The key is to find the right triangle, here is the routine (assume `P` is the center of the speaker's head):

1. Shift the center of the ellipse (`O`) by both ends, results in two points `Q1, Q2`.
2. Get the intersection point of line `PQ1, PO, PQ2` with the ellipse, denote them as `P1, P2, P3`. This is the main step, which can be solved based on the solution posted [here](http://blog.csharphelper.com/2012/09/24/calculate-where-a-line-segment-and-an-ellipse-intersect-in-c.aspx).
3. Get the center point of line segment `PP3`, denote it as `Q`.
4. Get the triangle `QP1P2`.

To further make it editable on UI, we can bind all these needed points data to the values that can be computed real-time.

[image]